# Fully removing Resharper Ultimate from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, uninstallation

I was running Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper 8, and everything was fine and dandy untill I tried to install Jetbrain's Dottrace trial version. It brought with it something called Resharper Ultimate, which in turn made sure none of my Intellisense or Resharper features worked.

So I uninstalled Resharper Ultimate using the Windows uninstall feature. But Visual Studio seems to still consider it installed, because its options appears in the program's preferences dialog. Not to mention the top menu choice.

I have also tried installing Resharper 8 anew, in hopes that it will cleanse my machine of Ultimate, but it detects no previous installs. So now, I'm getting options dialogs for both Resharper and Resharper Ultimate. And none of the features work.

Plus I'm getting this error message when opening a solution with Resharper active:

[image]

I have looked at the mentioned XML file, but am not sure of what to make of it.

Comment: Apparently it was this easy, heh. http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/92672788-Uninstalling-new-NET-Tools-from-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution from [ReSharper Support Site](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545359-Uninstalling-new-NET-Tools-from-Visual-Studio):

> To completely remove new .NET tools from Visual Studio, please try the
>   following:
>
> Run ReSharper 9.x (new .NET Tools) installer once again - do you have
>   any products with status Repair? If so, please select Remove for them
>   and select Skip for others. If there are no items with Repair action,
>   please remove the following folder manually C:\Users{User
>   Name}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio{Visual Studio
>   version}\Extensions\JetBrains

Answer (score 0):

I would try to clean the registry as per [this article](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2012/12/28/how-to-unregister-a-visual-studio-package-extension/).

At the top of the blog post, there is a [continuation of this story](http://blog.spinthemoose.com/2013/01/02/the-correct-way-to-uninstall-visual-studio-packages-extensions/) which describes fow to finalize the fix of the issue you experience by removing manifest and package definitions of your VS extensions.

Hope it helps